# Dynamic size array in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to make use of Array of nodes with dynamic memory allocation so that I can increase the number of nodes at runtime. However I seem to be getting an error which is unknown to me. I am probably using the array in wrong way, so please check and correct me. listNo used in the code is an integer variable.

Code:

```
Node* lists = (Node*) malloc(100 * sizeof(lists));

printf("\n Enter the number of lists:");
scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

if(nbrOfLists < 0)
    return -1;
if(nbrOfLists>100)
    lists = realloc(lists, 100 * sizeof(lists));


lists[listNo] = NULL;  // getting error here incompatible types assigning Node from type 'void*'
lists[listNo]= insertValue(lists[listNo], val);
```

I mean each element in an array has first element of an individual linked list. The next element is another independent first node of another linked list.

Comment: do you want array of nodes or array of node pointers?

Comment: I suggest further reading about pointers and arrays.

Comment: array of node pointers. Each array element is a node pointing to next node in a list

Comment: You should declare a few variables first such as listNo, val, nbrOfLists and It looks like Node is your own invented data type? So you need to define that too. is it a struct?

Comment: _array of node pointers_ vs _Each array element is a node_ - it is contradiction

Comment: I mean each element in an array has first element of an individual linked list.

Comment: Anyone there to help?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh if each element of your array is node - how you can assign NULL to it? it is not pointer, it is object/struct

Comment: @Lashane then what should I do? For first insertion of a node into linked list we need this check that it currently is null

Comment: @AbhishekSingh it is XY problem, why do you want to check that it currently null?

Answer (score 1):

For linked list you do not need to allocate memory for all elements. You have to have single root element `Node * root` and link all other to it. No need from `malloc` and `realloc` - that is the idea of "linked list". In your example you have dynamic array of objects.

Comment: I mean each element in an array has first element of an individual linked list.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should learn pointers concepts. Code signals you don't understand it well. Just friendly long term note.
2. `lists` has type of `pointer to Node` which is "address", in 32-bit OS it is 4 bytes, in 64 bit - 8 bytes. But no relation to actual `Node` structure size.
3. When you do `malloc(N * sizeof(lists)) you actually allocate N elements, each of which is address (4 or 8 bytes, again no relation to actually stored information).
4. When you refer to `lists[X]` you actually say "take this address of `Node`, and then take X-th `Node` under it". You mean `Node`, not "address of `Node`" so your compiler says "I cannot assign `Node` with NULL".

Hope this helps.
Please re-check pointers concept in C. Blocking issue for many people to grow further.

To say "please allocate N elements of type `Node`" you should write something like:

```
Node *lists = realloc(lists, N * sizeof(*lists));
```

And you'd better say `Node *list` than `Node* list` (practically it results the same code but please check what is the difference - it is basic principle and you should learn it yourself).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. However, I am able to achieve what I want using Node *lists[100]; but not the above method. Anyways I will revise my concepts again.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, do you understand that if you declare something like `Node *lists[100]` you actually have just `100 pointers to Node`? Is it your real goal? As far as I understand you need pointer to 100 `Node` structures. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of pointers to nodes, then you need a pointer to the first pointer to node of an array of pointers to nodes. This would be a double pointer for a variable sized array:   node **arrayofpoitnerstonode; , then arrayofpoitnerstonode[0] would be the first pointer to a node, arrayofpoitnerstonode[1] would be the second pointer to a node, ... .